# Build processing, Build first appears like below after that its not appears in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm facing this issue, build successfully Uploaded in Xcode but Build first appears like bellow after that its not appears in iTunes connect. Why I'm facing this issue?

[image: build processing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you received any email from Apple. Are you perhaps not receiving those emails?

Only 'Admin' and 'App Manager' user roles will receive those emails.

This scenario usually occurs if there is a problem with your binary, which Apple then explain to you in an email.

Comment: Sure, please go to **Users and Roles** in iTunes Connect and look for _your email address_. What **Role** do you have? Only 'Admin' and 'App Manager' roles will receive those emails.

The reason I'm asking this is because I think your 'Admin' user has received an email about an invalid binary. E.g. You're missing some app icons, or you have configured push incorrectly, access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description etc.
The only way to know for sure is when you can check if you're receiving those emails.

Comment: Thank you for valid information.but if that Admin is not with me now is there any way to know that issue. because it is our client email id.

Comment: I thought so ;]

Your client is receiving those emails now. You can simply request to change your user to 'Admin' or 'App Manager'. I don't think there is any other way to know...